# Get user profile pic from O365 - microsoft graph api

Tags: angularjs, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried to get user profile pic from O365 using Microsoft Graph API. When I used following API it returns only the metadata related to the profile pic.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo

Through https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value returns a gibberish object which doesn't make any sense. However, I believe that it is the data related to the user profile. Need help to extract those data into base64.

Comment: This should be a data stream - jpeg image. What platform/language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The returned data is the binary data of the image type. If you use JavaScript to retrieve the user photo, please get the photo data as blob type in a XMLHttpRequest, and then retrieve the blob URL from the response. For your reference:

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
 var photoUri=config.endpoints.graphApiUri + "/v1.0/me/photo/$value";
 request.open("GET",photoUri);
 request.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
 request.responseType = "blob";
 request.onload = function (){

 if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){

 var image = document.createElement("img");
 var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 var blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(request.response);
 image.src = blobUrl;
  document.getElementById("UserShow").appendChild(image);
 }

 };
 request.send(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

For making that photo viewable in view we have to convert the response in 64 byte.
I have make this done in by project by below code. Hope this answer useful for someone..

```
 HttpResponseMessage response1 =  await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/96x96/$value");
 using (Stream responseStream = await response1.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\image.jpg", FileMode.Create))
 {
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    responseStream.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
   string result = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
    HttpContext.Session[AppConstants.UserImage] = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", result);
    responseStream.Close();
    }
}
```